# How to mount external SSD with encrypte APFS volume very early during boot?

Tags: macos, startup, launchd, mount

I have an external SSD connected to my MacBook Pro (2021, M1, macOS Vetura). On the external drive is an encrypted APFS partition. I installed some huge applications to that external drive to save internal drive space.

To ensure that this drive is mounted early during boot, I created a launchd "daemon", whose plist looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

        <key>Label</key>
        <string>mount_external_ssd</string>

        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Library/Scripts/Boot/mount_external_ssd.sh</string>

        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>

        <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
        <true/>

</dict>
</plist>
```

and the script it calls looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/diskutil apfs          \
        unlockVolume <volumeID>  \
        -passphrase <passphrase>
```

with `<volumeID>` being the UUID of the volume and `<passphrase>` being the password of the encrypted APFS volume.

This all seems to work as expected. The drive is always mounted during boot prior to the desktop even showing up on screen and I can start the apps from that drive just fine.

Except there are some issues. Quite often when starting the app, the system needs to re-verify the app first (checking its signature) and once the app has been started, I get a notification that asks me to allow this app sending me notification, as if the app has just been freshly installed. Also any notification settings I configured last time are lost after every reboot. And if the app has a permanent place on my Dock, the app is displayed only as big question mark after boot, as if it was missing. However, when clicking the question mark, the app starts just fine and the icon is restored immediately.

So apparently the system seems to check for the presence of those apps even earlier during boot and since it cannot find them (the volume is not yet mounted I assume), it considers the apps to have been uninstalled and so it cleans up the verification status, the notification settings and tags the app as missing in the Dock.

This may also be related to the fact that I use autologin as well. My main APFS volume is also encrypted and requires me to enter my user password very early during boot (actually before the real boot has even started) but then I get automatically logged in without having to enter my password again and without a login screen being shown.

Is there a way I can mount my volume even earlier during boot, so the apps are found when the system checks for them? macOS doesn't seem to have a `/etc/fstab` file, does it? Or does anyone know a way how I can ensure that the system will wait during boot until my mount daemon has performed its job before logging in my user or checking for apps?

Comment: Mac can use fstab, but you need to make it yourself if it's not present. I have no idea *when* items load during the boot sequence - however, you'd usually use fstab to prevent loading rather than initiate it. Drives will auto-mount if enumerated during boot (& nothing is preventing them.)

Comment: @Tetsujin When they automount, the entire desktop system is already up, this way too late. That's even later than when my current LaunchDaemon mounts it and already that is too late.